# PHP: How to move uploaded file?

Tags: php, html, mysql

PHP code:

```
$target_path='uploads/';
//$target_path=$target_path.basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$res=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$target_path);
if($res)
//perform insert query
else
//echo 'file not uploaded';
```

HTML code:

```
<td colspan="3"> <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo"> </td>
```

After execution the image file is not moved to target_path folder. Also, The value of $res remains empty.

I need the value of $res as i want to perform insertion query if the variable has "true" as value.

There are no errors in the uploaded file. It exists and so does the target_path. There is no file with same name in target_path folder either.

Comment: have you checked the file error is 0?

Comment: Does your upload folder has the permission?

Comment: echo $target_path after you call $target_path.basename(). I have never seen the dot notation used like that in PHP so clearly you're doing something incorrect. I believe you are meant to be calling basename($_FILES...) instead.

Comment: @Sankalp - upload folder has permissions.

Comment: @max_ even if i comment that line the code doesn't work.

Comment: Can you do `print_r($_FILES);` and post it here..could give some pointers to any issues.

Comment: print_r($_FILES); shows o/p as "Array ( )"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i simply used copy() instead of move_uploaded_files and it worked. Note that i don't have enctype mentioned in my form. Don't know if that was the cause move_uploaded_files wasn't working. But copy() definitely works without it.

Also consider what oldskool commented above

"$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] will hold the full path to the upload, something like /tmp/asx823ASDfg, so using this syntax will result /upload//tmp/asx823ASDfg, which is an absolute path to a (most likely) unexisting folder. – Oldskool

Answer (score 0):

Is your file input inside a form element in your HTML? And have you definitely got enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form element?

If you have the above, then do this to debug what's going on. This will print out the files array so you can see if there's a problem:

```
exit(var_dump($_FILES));
$target_path='uploads/';
//$target_path=$target_path.basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$res=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$target_path);
if($res)
//perform insert query
else
//echo 'file not uploaded';
```

Answer (score 0):

thisis an working code

```
$target_path='/uploads/';
$target_path=$target_path.uniqid().$_FILES['upload_photo']['name'];
$res=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_photo']['tmp_name'],$target_path);
if($res)
//perform insert query
else
//echo 'file not uploaded';

 <input type="file" name="upload_photo" id="upload_photo">
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this way..

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],
    "/upload/".$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);`

Comment: $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] will hold the full path to the upload, something like `/tmp/asx823ASDfg`, so using this syntax will result `/upload//tmp/asx823ASDfg`, which is an absolute path to a (most likely) unexisting folder.